# iOS how to capture touches within any view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, touch, gestures

I'm looking for a way to capture (X,Y) locations of touches that user might be making within screens my app (relative to most backward view of a view controller).

Is there a way for me to subclass some kind of (UIResponder?) or add a category on a UIView **to be able to intercept touches, process them, but still allow them to interact with the content** (buttons, gesture recognizers, etc)?

I was thinking of implementing "touchesBegan:", but in my experience that frequently messes up existing button or gesture recognizer logic.

Comment: Only one responder is allowed to handle touches, AFAIK.

Comment: I was thinking more of a passthrough behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible up to some limits. There is a sample project on [**GitHub**](https://github.com/toddreed/Touchpose) by **Todd Reed**, you can also use that code and modify it for your needs.

Having a quick look at the code, it is keeping a custom `UIWindow` on top using **swizzled** methods and rendering touches on that view. It is also using `sendEvent:` method of the `UIApplication` class, which redirects the events down the view hierarchy.

This is a much more elegant solution than using `UIGestureRecognizer` on each view controller. Many analytics solutions are also doing this very effectively.

Answer (score 1):

you could have a base View Controller that is a UIGestureRecognizerDelegate that each of your view controllers subclass that has a gesture recognizer on to listen for touches.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    ...

    UIGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UIGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(gestureAction:)];
    [gestureRecognizer setEnabled:YES];
    [gestureRecognizer setCancelsTouchesInView:NO];
    [gestureRecognizer setDelaysTouchesBegan:NO];
    [gestureRecognizer setDelaysTouchesEnded:NO];
    [gestureRecognizer setDelegate:self];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
...
}
```

and then have your gesture recognizer code

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch{
    NSLog(@"view touch (%f,%f)",[touch locationInView:self.view].x,[touch locationInView:self.view].y);
    return YES;
}
```